# Why on earth is my apostrophe character represented as `&#8217;`?

Tags: linux-mint, text

`'` = `&#8217;`?

I'm running Linux Mint 19.1 with Cinnamon, and I notice that in all instances where the system has to display the apostrophe character, it instead displays this string `&#8217;` which seems to be a unicode type code to define the character. I just wonder how to get my system to display the actual apostrophe character instead of this code.

Comment: Your text contains the Unicode character Right Single Quotation Mark instead of the apostrophe you are expecting. You will have to go to the source of the problem: which editor or program produced the character?

Comment: Are you saying that for instance `printf '\u2019\n'` at a shell prompt in a terminal emulator outputs `&#8217;`. Is your web browser  outputting that for `’`?

Comment: Note that in your `' = &#8217;`, the `'` is the U+0027 character (apostrophe, `&#39;`), not U+2019 (`’`, `&#8217;` right quotation mark, sometimes used as apostrophe as well where `'` is rendered vertically).

Comment: I have never seen the system actively change character codes, but I have plenty of war stories of such problems being tracked to some data (file name, code snippets...), being copied from Word documents where some "helpful" word processor changed the representation of quotes or dashes (the worst offender being  a zero-width non-breaking space in the middle of a file name...).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas It's in a way that whenever I get *any* notification with an apostrophe in it, it outputs the above string in its place.

Comment: What's a "notification"?  Twitter? E-mail? `write bob /dev/tty3`?